# How to change game object Material in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I do if cube1 collision cube2, cube1 [material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmOwB.png) = yesil ?
I'm new in Unity and English speaking sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the material of the **Mesh Renderer** component of the game object. Hence, get a reference to the **Mesh Renderer** and change its material.

```
red.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = yesil;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change material on Editor(it will also work at Runtime), use `sharedMaterial` instead `material` property.

This will work in Editor and at Runtime.

```cs
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = yesil;
```

This will work just at Runtime.

```cs
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = yesil;
```